# Disable all user input events on Cordova/PhoneGap

Tags: javascript, events, cordova, block

I would like to temporary disable all touch/virtual keyboard events in a hybrid Cordova/PhoneGap app. Is there some kind of plug-in to achieve this natively? Perhaps something, that disables the whole web view from any user input. If there isn't one, how can this be achieved with javascript/CSS/HTML?

P.S. I need this feature in order to make sure the user won't disturb the predefined animated scenario.

Comment: Untested: `document.body.addEventListener("click", function(e) {e.preventDefault();});`

Comment: Or perhaps add a transparent layer that covers the entire viewport.

Comment: As @RonaldPK as suggested a Modal(transparent) element which stays on top (Z-index higher than other elements) and then prevent the default event i.e `modalElement.addEventListener("click", function(e) {e.preventDefault();});` This would be simple effective solution and compatible across all browsers.

Answer (score 0):

You can use javascript or a overlay to handle this.

Using javascript

```
var handler = document.addEventListener('click, touchEnd, touchStart, touch, keypress', function (evt) {
  evt.stopPropagation();
  evt.preventDefault();
});
```

Once your animation is complete use below to remove blocker;

```
handler.removeEventListener();
```

Or create a div with css

```
.overlay {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: block;
  z-index: 999999;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
```

Once your animation is complete you can hide the div or remove it.